# How to create an array of two data types for TableView Sections - Cannot Assign Through Subscript: Subscript is a get-only

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am trying to add sections to my table view. I need the first section to be an array of strings and the second section to be an array of `NSManagedObjects`, I use a fetch request to add the data to the array.

I add the section titles to the sections array.

```
let sections = ["Upcoming", "Checklist Notebooks"]
```

Then have a dictionary for the data

```
var sectionItems = [

    "Upcoming" : ["1","2", "3", "4"],

    "Objects" : [Object]()

]
```

However when doing the fetch request I get the following error,

> Cannot Assign Through Subscript: Subscript is a get-only

Here's my fetch request,

```
self.sectionItems["Objects"] = delegate.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Object]
```

How can I create an array/dictionary of two data types to used for the sections ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add definition for your compound dictionary. You can try this in the playground.

```
var sectionItems: [String: [Any]] = [

    "Upcoming" : ["1","2", "3", "4"],

    "Objects" : [AnyObject]()

]

sectionItems["Objects"] = ["123"]

sectionItems["Objects"]
```

Comment: @KSDEV did you try this?